# "The good parts" for an existing collection

Tags: rel-canonical

I have an existing collection at https://cjshayward.com which is everything I've created, and intended to be unfiltered.

I want to set https://cshayward.com (no "J") to be a "The Good Parts" website.

An implementation question I am facing is which are live option(s):

1. Linking from a https://cshayward.com page to e.g. https://cjshayward.com/letters/, and/or:
2. Setting up a copy at https://cshayward.com/letters/ with a rel="canonical" link to https://cjshayward.com/letters/.

Is the second option in some way bad, or is making a copy with rel="canonical" "clean" as far as search engines are concerned?

Comment: What's the purpose of having a website that just has the good parts of some other website?

Comment: One website is "everything but the kitchen sink"; the intended other site is just the best stuff so people will only find best works.

Comment: Why not just make the good stuff on your website more prominent and hide the other stuff?

Comment: I've already done something like that, but I want the complete works to be available, and not break incoming links, and have a way to point people to best works. [The main site](https://cjshayward.com) has multiple megabytes of text and [a best works collection on Amazon](https://cjshayward.com/bjc) at 700+ pages is still less than one tenth of the work. I want my whole works to be available, and have something I can point people to my best works without impairing full functioning of incoming links to the works they were linked to. There are dual first-class interests.